# GCP Billing Account Administrator cannot perform actions it is supposed to - using Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-iam

I have a project in GCP and billing account connected to it. I want to create budget and set some alarms for obvious reasons. I want to manage it with Terraform. Unfortunately, I got errors telling me, that I cannot perform certain actions, even though GCP docs for roles and permissions tell me that I should be able to.

I created ServiceAccount to manage my Terraform. Here is the code:

```
variable "billing_account" {
  type        = string
}

resource "google_project" "A" {
  name            = "A"
  project_id      = local.project
  billing_account = var.billing_account
  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
}


resource "google_project_service" "A-service" {
  project                    = google_project.A.project_id
  disable_dependent_services = true
  for_each                   = toset(["cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com", "iam.googleapis.com", "serviceusage.googleapis.com", "cloudbilling.googleapis.com"])
  service                    = each.value
}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "A-editor-member" {
  project = google_project.A.project_id
  role    = "roles/editor"
  member  = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.A-service.email}"
}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "A-sa-member" {
  project    = google_project.A.project_id
  for_each   = toset(["roles/iam.securityAdmin", "roles/container.admin", "roles/storage.admin"])
  role       = each.value
  member     = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.A-service.email}"
}
```

So far, everything worked fine. The problem occurred, when I want to add `roles/billing.admin` as another role to my ServiceAccount

```
resource "google_billing_account_iam_member" "A-billing-manager" {
  billing_account_id = var.billing_account
  role               = "roles/billing.admin"
  member             = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.A-service.email}"
}
```

After applying this code I get: `Error: Error retrieving IAM policy for billing account "XYZ": googleapi: Error 403: The caller does not have permission, forbidden`. Caller should have permission, because it is `BillingAccountAdministrator` (also I checked with all other roles given in the same moment eg.`BillingAccountViewer`)

Anyway, I decided to abandon creating it with ServiceAccount for now and do it with my UserAccount.

```
resource "google_billing_budget" "budget" {
  billing_account = var.billing_account
  display_name = "A-budget"

  amount {
    specified_amount {
      currency_code = "USD"
      units = 50
    }
  }

  for_each = toset([for v in var.threshholds : tostring(v)]) # terraform does not support for_each(list(NUMBER))

  threshold_rules {
    threshold_percent = each.value
  }
}
```

After applying it, I got: `Error: Error creating Budget: googleapi: Error 403: The caller does not have permission`

The caller of `terraform apply` is my UserAccount, which is both owner of the project and billing account administrator (and more...).

Can you please tell what can be wrong with my UserAccount? The problem must be on my site since its basic functionality and it cannot be bugged

Thank you in advance!